# Google analytics goal and query string impartial tracking

Tags: google-analytics

We have set up a goal in GA, which should end up in /welcome.

To track this, we have added these goal funnels:

1. "/"
2. "/join"
3. "/join?x="
4. "/welcome" (Goal URL)

Sometimes the parameter x is filled, sometimes not. We're using "Head match" in Match type.

GA tracks the end goal ok, but on step 3 its always 100% conversion rate.

Heres a screenshot of the goal funnel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4AN6.jpg

"Bli medlem (skjema)" is step 3.

How do we set up GA to track the third URL correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regular expression match instead of head match as this ignores parameters at the end of the url.

Make sure to put a backslash before the question mark like so `/join\?x=` to prevent it from meaning something else in regex.